# php mysql query works in phpmyadmin but not on webpage

Tags: php, mysql

i wrote the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(userID) From statistics WHERE userID = ""
```

this query displays the number of unathunticated visit to the website.

the query works in phpmyadmin when i use double quotes however it doesnt when i use single quotes like below it just gives me the number of record stored in the table

```
 $queryB = "SELECT COUNT(userID) From statistics WHERE userID = ''";
 $resultB =mysql_query($queryA, $con) or die(mysql_error());
 $authB = mysql_result($resultB, "COUNT(userID)");

 echo "the number of authenticated visits were $authB<br />\n";
```

i've no idea why it breaks, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if it will work...its just first think that came to mind:
how about when u use escaped double quotes?

$queryB = "SELECT COUNT(userID) From statistics WHERE userID = \"\""

Answer (score 4):

you store your query in `$queryB` but you use `$queryA`

Comment: +1 nice catch.I would bet that `$queryA` was a test with no `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $queryB = "SELECT COUNT(userID) AS total From statistics WHERE userID = ''";
 $resultB =mysql_query($queryB, $con) or die(mysql_error());
$authB = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultB);
 echo "the number of authenticated visits were ".$authB['total']."<br />\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Does userID have a default value? If the default value is NULL, then change your query to

```
$queryB = "SELECT COUNT(userID) From statistics WHERE userID IS NULL";
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change a little to your code

```
$queryB = "SELECT COUNT(userID) From statistics WHERE userID = ''";
$resultB =mysql_query($queryB, $con) or die(mysql_error());
$authB = mysql_result($resultB, 0, 0);

echo "the number of authenticated visits were $authB<br />\n";
```